# Removing Clyde from user count of sharding

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get the accurate user count (minus Clyde from each guild of each shard);

But my code seems to include Clyde in each guild.

How would I remove Clyde from each?

#### Code

```js
let users = await client.shard.broadcastEval("this.users.cache.size");
let totalUsers = users.reduce((acc, userCount) => acc + userCount, 0);
```

Comment: `Collection.prototype.size` returns a number, not an array. How are you using `reduce()`?

Comment: It works this way for some reason not only that this section of code came from [Discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide)